# Django installation and import with two Pythons

Tags: django, python-3.x, import, installation

I'm trying to install Django on my computer, but none of the method I followed seems to work. I tried with pip as described on the Django website, I tried with the setup.py file, and when the installation is done with both  methods, I can't import Django :

```
ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

For information, I have two Python 3.3 on my computer (32 and 64 bits) in case it change something.

Thanks for helping.
T.

Comment: Did you try http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/? Don't forget to activate your virtualenv before running Django.

Comment: Hum I didn't know I need that for a local Web app but I've done it anyway and it still doesn't work.

Comment: what is your system? (windows, linux, mac?)

Comment: to follow up on @Filly's answer: `virtualenv` is a great tool.  Once setting up an environment, you can install different Python versions without the system getting confused.  I'm also a fan of `virtualenvwrapper`.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 64 bits, and I must create Windows installer for both 32 and 64 bits of my Python program.